# Quantum Mechanics Griffiths Problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, complex-numbers, spherical-harmonics

I was doing problem no. $4.4$ from Griffiths Third Edition. I cannot understand one thing related to the solution of the normalization of $Y_2^1$.
$$Y_2^1 = -\sqrt{\frac{15}{8\pi}}e^{i\phi}sin\theta cos\theta $$

The solution manual shows:
[image]

Where did the $e^{i\phi}$ term go?

Comment: Taking the magnitude, and $|e^{i\phi}| = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The squared norm of a vector of a complex Hilbert space is $|v|=+\sqrt{\langle v \vert v\rangle }$, and in this particular Hilbert space the inner product of two vectors is $\langle v|g\rangle =\int d\mu \, v^{*}g$.
So in this case, the squared norm would be $\int d\Omega |Y_{2}^{1}|=\int d\Omega\frac{15}{8\pi}\sin^{2}\theta \cos^{2}\theta e^{i\phi} e^{-i\phi}$ where I intentionally did not simplify the last two exponentials for you to know why it "disappears" in the integral.